# How do I get a cuFunction from a __global__ function I've written?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Suppose I want to use CUDA's lower-level driver API on some source I've written. I know about `cuLaunchKernel`, but I can't seem to find in the docs the exact explanation of how you get the `cuFunction` to pass to it from your `__global__` functions,.

Comment: take a look at the CUDA sample codes that use the driver API, such as [vectorAddDrv](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition-driver-api).  The project is set up to compile the kernel (`__global__` function in vectorAddDrv_kernel.cu) to ptx, and the kernel in ptx form is loaded via an API sequence in the vectorAddDrv.cpp file.  The [driver API section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#driver-api) of the programming guide will also be useful as a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [cuModuleGetFunction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html#group__CUDA__MODULE_1ga52be009b0d4045811b30c965e1cb2cf). The function name you pass must be the mangled C++ name if you are not using C linkage. You can get that using cuobjdump on a compiled version of your device source.

Comment: But do I _have_ to load the module from a file, or do I somehow magically get a module built in to my executable/loaded by default/etc.?

Comment: You either load a precompiled binary from a cubin or fat binary file which you build a priori, or PTX code which you either wrote or compiled from source. You can also initiate a runtime device linker session if you have device code libraries to link against.

Comment: I get it, but can't I somehow have my executable file be my fat binary as well? I mean, that's what the runtime API does essentially, right?

Comment: No, you can't really do that. The runtime API uses several internal functions and a lot of compiler driven boilerplate to work its magic. You would affectively be inventing your own runtime API, which seems pointless.

Comment: That's what what missing for me. Well, too bad.